# IIS7 Migrate web.config from classic to integrated issue

Tags: iis-7, module, iis-6, httpmodule

I have a webservice which defines a custom httpmodule.  I am attempting to launch this webservice onto a production server running IIS7 but have only been able to get it to run in Classic mode.

I have tried moving this section

```
 <system.web>
<httpModules>
  <add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" type="MyProject.UserAuthenticator.UserNameAuthenticator" />
</httpModules>
...
```

To the system.webserver section like so:

```
  <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="BasicAuthenticationModule" type="MyProject.UserAuthenticator.UserNameAuthenticator" />
</modules>
```

When I try this IE gives me this error:

```
  Config Error
  Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to          
  'BasicAuthenticationModule'
```

I also attempted to migrate automatically with the following DOS command:

```
  appcmd migrate config "mysite/"
```

And get this message back:

```
  The module BasicAuthenticationModule with type "mytype" is already present in the application with a different type"", and was not migrated
```

I am not an IIS expert so any insights are appreciated.

---

So after a little research it appears there is already a native module called BasicAuthenticationModule.  I can eliminate my issue by renaming my module "BasicCustomAuthenticationModule."  Is this the correct approach or should I be removing the other one?

Thanks!
AFrieze

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Their was a conflict in the name BasicAuthenticationModule.  The solution was to rename the module.

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="BasicCustomAuthenticationModule" type="MyProject.UserAuthenticator.UserNameAuthenticator" />
</httpModules>


    <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="BasicCustomAuthenticationModule" type="MyProject.UserAuthenticator.UserNameAuthenticator" />
</modules>
```